# GMail (SMTP over TLS) mail send proxy

Tags: email, proxy, smtp

I have an application that needs to send e-mails, but it only supports standard plain SMTP over port 25. We are using Google GSuite though, so sending emails over port 25 is not possible.

Is there a program that can listen on port 25 and relay all mails to smtp.google.com where I authenticate and use TLS?

It should be a simple solution, I am not looking for a full blown qmail or sendmail solution.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://superuser.com/questions/1365179/advanced-port-redirection-windows-firewall

Comment: @TDK thanks, but I am looking for a higher level proxy, not just plain port forwarding. The application will need to log in to GMail and do TLS as well.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't need an extra application. GSuite allows plain SMTP sending (with some restrictions), that can be IP based and set up through the admin panel.

More info here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en